# Regex para pegar somente uma ocorrencia da equerda para a direita

Tags: regex

Procuro uma Regex para pegar somente o IP da direita. Ja tentei algumas coisas mas não consigo descobrir, essa foi a regex que me pareceu dar mais certo `/((?[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})\s/g` porém ela não pega os IP's que estão entre parênteses, acredito não ser a melhor forma para montar a expressão. PS: deixei em negrito os valores que quero pegar com a regex.

Nmap scan report for whm.ixcsoft.com.br (**45.174.128.220**)
Host is up (0.047s latency).
Nmap scan report for 231.128.174.45.ixcsoft.com.br (**45.174.128.231**)
Host is up (0.048s latency).
Nmap scan report for **192.168.25.2**
Host is up (0.048s latency).
Nmap scan report for **192.168.25.3**
Host is up (0.048s latency).

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplesmente remova o `\s` e os parênteses redundantes, a menos que sua expressão regular seja uma captura em uma maior: `(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(?=\s|\)|$)`.

Adicione também uma afirmação antecipada `(?=\s|\)|$)` para garantir que o endereço IP seja seguido por um espaço em branco, fechando parênteses ou nova linha.

https://regex101.com/r/pYwRXy/2.

Desculpe, se meu português é imperfeito.

Comment: Assim ele pega mais de uma match por linha, ou seja se eu rodar sem vai pegar os dois IP's da linha quando quero pegar somente o ultimo.

 Nmap scan report for **231.128.174.45**.ixcsoft.com.br (**45.174.128.231**)

Comment: @Krisque, veja a resposta atualizada.